# Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined

Tags: authentication, onclick, syntax-error

I tried to make this using chatgpt but it always error manytime. Can you help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login and Play</title>
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center;
            }
            h1 {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }
            .login-form {
                margin: 50px auto;
                width: 300px;
            }
            .login-form input {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .login-form button {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #4caf50;
                color: white;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login and Play</h1>
        <div class="login-form"><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nama" /> <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /> <button onclick="login()">Login</button></div>
        <script>
              function login() {
                var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                if (password === 'user123') {
                  showPlayOptions(name);
                } else {
                  alert('Password Salah');
                }
              }
              function showPlayOptions(name) {
                document.body.innerHTML = `
                  <h1>Selamat Datang, ${name}!<\/h1>
                  <div>
                    <h2>Pilih Waktu Bermain:<\/h2>
                    <input type="radio" name="time" value="30" id="time-30">
                    <label for="time-30">30 Menit - Harga: 1000<\/label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="time" value="60" id="time-60">
                    <label for="time-60">1 Jam - Harga: 2000<\/label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="time" value="180" id="time-180">
                    <label for="time-180">3 Jam - Harga: 2500<\/label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="time" value="1440" id="time-1440">
                    <label for="time-1440">1 Hari - Harga: 5000<\/label><br>
                    <button onclick="confirmTime()">Confirm<\/button>
                  <\/div>
                `;
              }
              function confirmTime() {
                var selectedTime = document.querySelector('input[name="time"]:checked');
                if (selectedTime) {
                  var timeValue = selectedTime.value;
                  var timeText = selectedTime.nextSibling.textContent;
                  var price = timeText.match(/Harga: (\d+)/)[1];
                  showTimer(timeValue, price);
                }
              }
              function showTimer(timeValue, price) {
                var timerSeconds = timeValue * 60;
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                  var minutes = Math.floor(timerSeconds / 60);
                  var seconds = timerSeconds % 60;
                  if (timerSeconds === 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    showTimeExpired();
                  }
                  document.body.innerHTML = `
                    <h1>Waktu Anda: ${minutes}:${padZero(seconds)}<\/h1>
                    <div>
                      <label for="name">Nama Pengunjung:<\/label>
                      <input type="text" id="name" value="${name}" disabled>
                    <\/div>
                             <div>
                      <label for="selected-time">Waktu yang Dipilih:<\/label>
                      <input type="text" id="selected-time" value="${timeValue} Menit" disabled>
                    <\/div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="price">Harga:<\/label>
                      <input type="text" id="price" value="${price}" disabled>
                    <\/div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="timer">Timer:<\/label>
                      <input type="text" id="timer" disabled>
                    <\/div>
                    <button onclick="addTime()">Tambah Waktu<\/button>
                    <button onclick="exit()">Keluar<\/button>
                  <\/div>
                    `;
                startTimer(timerSeconds);
              }
            }
            function startTimer(timerSeconds) {
              var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
              var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var minutes = Math.floor(timerSeconds / 60);
                var seconds = timerSeconds % 60;
                if (timerSeconds === 0) {
                  clearInterval(interval);
                  showTimeExpired();
                }
                timer.value = `${minutes}:${padZero(seconds)}`;
                timerSeconds--;
              }, 1000);
            }
            function padZero(value) {
              return value < 10 ? '0' + value : value;
            }
            function addTime() {
              showPlayOptions(name);
            }
            function exit() {
              document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Terima kasih!<\/h1>';
            }
            function showTimeExpired() {
              document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Waktu Anda Sudah Habis<\/h1>' +
                '<button onclick="addTime()">Tambah Waktu<\/button>' +
                '<button onclick="exit()">Keluar<\/button>';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to make an application for my internet cafe so that when a customer wants to use it it can be like this, btw this is just an example and not the real thing. It always says Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined